# The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to authenticate to Dynamics CRM 365 and  following [these instructions](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/johntowgood/2018/02/12/dynamics-365-online-authenticate-with-user-credentials)

My problem is that I don't know what is the property 'grant_type'

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article you linked I think it should be the word "password".

`grant_type=password`

Comment: I still got "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type" !